# MVC 4 - how to save an edited dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

An entity of mine posesses a dictionary to save a float for a specific datetime:

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, float> PriceDictionary;
```

In the constructor of that entity, I add say 200 datetimes with a default value of 0 for the float-value to any new object.

The Edit-View of that entity displays the dictionary like this

```
    @foreach (var p in Model.PriceDictionary)
        {
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => p.Key)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => p.Value)
            </div>
        }
```

The value is editable and all values are in the postback, e.g.:

```
...p.Key=2012%2F02%2F02&p.Value=50&p.Key=2012%2F02%2F03&p.Value=0...
```

The problem is that changed values are not saved. I guess I have to adjust the Controller for Http-Post, but I am not sure what to do and would be glad if somebody could give me a hint (or two). So far, the controller looks like this:

```
db.Entry(stockposition).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Is there a better solution to this? Please bear with me.. I'm a C# freshman and have started MVC only 5 days ago.

Comment: [Freshman?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5GEDajZfjc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this post from Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

It explains how you can bind to Dictionaries.

Basically it just boils down to making sure that the names of your fields are correct:

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, that looks interesting and suitable. I'll give it a try after a smoke.

Comment: I guess I'm a little bit too stupid right now to implement what Scott Hanselman advises. I got the final HTML to look like what he writes but .. no change, nothing got saved. Now, I have created a class "Price" that has propertys value and date and in the "Parent" entity, I added a public virtual List<Price> Prices { get; set; }. Is this a bad solution for a reason? It's working, at last..